# Computing line integrals when you know the curves

Tags: vector-analysis

Consider the vector field

$$F=(x^2+y^2,3xy).$$ 
Compute the line integrals 
$$\int_{c_1}F⋅dr \text{ and } \int_{c_2}F⋅dr,$$ where $$C_1(t)=(t,t^2) \text{ and } C_2(t)=(t,t)$$ for $0≤t≤1$. Can you decide from your answers whether or not F is a gradient vector field? Why or why not?

I tried substituting the parameters of $C_1$ with $x$ and $y$; $x = t, y = t^2$. Then  performing the dot product of $F$ with the derivative of $C_1$ from $0$ to $1$, but that didn't work.
$$\int_0^1F⋅dt = \int_0^1[(t^2 + t^4), 3t^3] \cdot [1, 2t] dt$$ 
I know that F is not conservative because they will not equal each other because they will be different integrals under different paths.
I don't understand what to do with the $C_1$.

Comment: I edited your post to have proper markdown. In doing so, I assumed that $(t,t2)$ and $(x2 + y2)$ meant $(t,t^2)$ and $(x^2 + y^2)$. Is this correct?

Comment: "I tried performing the dot product of $F$ with the derivative of $C_1$ from $0$ to $1$, but that didn't work." -- What exactly didn't work? The two integrals do have different values. You should post your work on computing them. Without seeing your work, nobody can tell what went wrong in it.

Comment: @zipirovich I fixed it.

Comment: Then why don't you keep on working on it? First of all, the right-hand side must be an integral as well. Then for $x$ and $y$ you must substitute their parametrizations along the curve, $C_1$ in this case. Then evaluate the dot product. Then integrate.